# Django get multiple latest elements using filter

Tags: python, django, filter

I have two models and I want to use haystack to search inside them.

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class PageRevision(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='revisions')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.page
```

I want to filter the PageRevions so that I get the latest page revisions of all pages, so old revisions of pages won't deliver searchresults.
First I thought that I could loop over all pages and then store the last revision in a list,

```
all_pages = Page.objects.all()
page_revisions = []
for page in all_pages:
    page_revisions.append(PageRevision.objects.filter(page=page).order_by('-created')[0])
```

but haystack needs a QuerySet object as a result, so somehow I need to use the filter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is get the ID numbers of the latest page revisions for each page, and then query for those IDs:

```
all_pages = Page.objects.all()
revision_ids = [p.revisions.order_by('-created').first().pk for p in all_pages]
page_revisions = PageRevision.objects.filter(pk__in=revision_ids)
```

Some caveats:

1. Does a lot of queries!
2. Does not handle cases in which a page has no revisions (but can easily be adapted to do so if need be).

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. I don't mind if it uses many queries, since this part of the code is only used during indexing of pages.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to perform union operation on querysets to combine all the querysets in the `page_revisions` list.**

The union operator for QuerySets is `|`, the pipe symbol.

```
qs1|qs2   # Union of two querysets 'qs1' and 'qs2'
```

The above code **returns a QuerySet** with all the items from `qs1` and all the items in `qs2` while handling duplicates i.e. items that are in both QuerySets will only appear once in the result.

So we will apply `|` union operator on each element of `page_revisions` list which are querysets with the help of `lambda` and `reduce()`.

```
combined_queryset = reduce(lambda x,y: x|y, page_revisions) # returns a queryset with all the querysets combined
```

The variable `combined_queryset` is of type `QuerySet` formed by the combination of all the querysets in the list `page_revisions`.

You can now pass the queryset `combined_queryset` to haystack to get the desired result.

**Note:** You need to append querysets to `page_revisions` list instead of objects for this to work.

Change `[0]` to `[:1]` in the below code fragment:

```
page_revisions.append(PageRevision.objects.filter(page=page).order_by('-created')[:1])
```